# CSS nesting before and lang

Tags: html, css

This is my code:

```
.lae-filter-item.segment-0:lang(pt-BR){
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Works great, but I also want to replace the content in segment-0 with a different word (just for Portuguese). :before or :after would be fine, but I can't nest it properly.  Here's what is not working.

```
.lae-filter-item.segment-0:before{
    lae-filter-item.segment-0:lang(pt-BR){
        content: "Hello";
            visibility: visible;
    }
}
```

and

```
.lae-filter-item.segment-0:before:lang(pt-BR){
        content: "Hello";
            visibility: visible;
    }
```

This works, but it adds the content for all the languages, not just Portuguese:

```
.lae-filter-item.segment-0:before{
content: "Hello";
visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: How looks HTML? Where lang is set?

Comment: I'm not sure I can add a screen shot here, but this is editing a taxonomy filter on a posts page (and there doesn't seem to be a way to do this inside wordpress.  Language is in the settings and the css code above works, I just don't know how to use the language selctor and the :before selector simultaneously.

Comment: Just show me the element  (and context related to this question) where lang is defined. Or add link to your page.

Comment: https://thebreedersalliance.com/index.php/pt/novidades/

Answer (score 0):

You nearly got it. The correct nesting is `.class:lang(pt-BR)::before {...}`.

Comment: ```
.lae-filter-item.segment-0:lang(pt-BR)::before{
 content: "Todos";
 visibility: visible;
}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working.  Can you see if I did something wrong?

Comment: In your case, you can do `html:lang(pt-BR) .lae-filter-item.segment-0::before {...}` since the `lang` attribute is in the `html` tag. Not sure if this is best practices, though.

Comment: Thanks.  I couldn't get that to work either.  As I look more into this, I'm realizing that this may not be possible with CSS.  I wanted to replace a menu item "All" for "Todos" - but hiding "All", which is what I was able to do, doesn't allow me to put a new link in.  From what I had been reading on other posts, hiding the visibility, and then using before and after was the way to do this - but I don't think it can apply to a menu item.

Answer (score 0):

The selector you're looking for is

```
[lang='pt-BR'] .lae-filter-item.segment-0:before {}
```

Or more specifity for better understanding

```
html[lang='pt-BR'] .lae-filter-item.segment-0:before {}
```

Lang isn't set directly at `.lae-filter-item`, so you can't use `.lae-filter-item[lang]` or other options you tried.